# Measure-valued function as transition kernel

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be Polish spaces. Consider $\mathcal{M}(Y)$, the space of (nonnegative) measures on $Y$, as a Polish space, equipped with the topology of weak convergence of measures.

Let $\mu_x:X\rightarrow \mathcal{M}(Y)$ be a Borel function. Is it then automatically the case that $f$ induces a transition kernel? In other words, does it follow that for any Borel subset $B$ of $Y$, we have that $ x \mapsto \mu_x (B)$ is measurable?

Comment: There is a problem with your notations: who is $x$ in $\mu_x$? And who is $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for probability measures, the answer is yes. This is a consequence of the result in [this math stackexchange article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1791592/probability-measures-equipped-with-weak-topology-is-p-mapsto-pa-measurable?rq=1), and is also stated and proved explicitly as Proposition 7.26 in [Bertsekas and Shreve's stochastic control book](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4852/chap5-7.pdf?sequence=4&isAllowed=y).